# check if some attributes of new row that I will insert it exist in this table or no and if yes do something by trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

This is my trigger, it should check if cargoPolicyNumber ,containerNumber are exist in CONTAINER_FEE table or no, if yes then will UPDATE extraFee ..
But when I run it
I faced the message “trigger is created with compilation error”

```
CREATE TRIGGER FEE_VIOLATION 
BEFORE INSERT ON CONTAINER_FEE 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT cargoPolicyNumber ,containerNumber FROM CONTAINER_FEE WHERE
new.cargoPolicyNumber = cargoPolicyNumber AND new.containerNumber = containerNumber)
   UPDATE CONTAINER_FEE 
   SET extraFee=extraFee+100 
    WHERE new.cargoPolicyNumber = cargoPolicyNumber AND new.containerNumber =
containerNumber; 
END IF 

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the table that is being modified in a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger. But you're likely modifying the row that is currently being inserted? In that case, you don't need an update statement, you can just change the value before it's inserted. Replace your update statement with:

```
:new.extraFee := :new.extraFee + 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You get error messages, because some little things are missing :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FEE_VIOLATION 
--> add "OR REPLACE" even if this is not a source of the error, you'll need this for future modifications
BEFORE INSERT ON CONTAINER_FEE 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT cargoPolicyNumber ,containerNumber FROM CONTAINER_FEE WHERE
new.cargoPolicyNumber = cargoPolicyNumber AND new.containerNumber = containerNumber)
THEN --> This is missing(Error)
   UPDATE CONTAINER_FEE 
   SET extraFee=extraFee+100 
    WHERE new.cargoPolicyNumber = cargoPolicyNumber AND new.containerNumber =
containerNumber; 
END IF; --> This semicolon is missing(Error) 

END;
/  --> you need this to compile the programming unit
```